# SharePoint Online Multi List Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, spquery

I have 2 lists one called Client and on called CombinedNotes. In combinedNotes I have a lookup field to Clients. In the Client list I have users assigned to Clients. I need to create a query that will show me a list of clients assigned to each user and which clients have not been seen in the last calendar week. Can someone help me with how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Do clients have access to your SharePoint Online Portal?

Comment: No just internal users